# MySql Query/PHP to get all column value with same customer name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not really sure how to word my problem for the title but here's what i'm trying to do. I have a table:

table1

```
-----------------------------------
| customer |   phone  | productid |
-----------------------------------
|   John   | 123-4567 |  P123     |
-----------------------------------
|   Bam    | 345-6789 |  P033     |
-----------------------------------
|   John   | 123-4567 |  P432     |
-----------------------------------
|   Gin   | 444-1234 |  P543     |
-----------------------------------
|   Bam    | 345-6789 |  P320     |
-----------------------------------
|   Bam    | 345-6789 |  P675     |
-----------------------------------
```

And I'm trying to get a result like this:

**Customer:** John 
**Phone :** 123-4567
**Products:** P123, P432

**Customer:** Bam
**Phone:** 345-6789
**Products:** P033, P320, P675

**Customer:** Gin
**Phone:** 444-1234
**Products:** P543

I'm not sure if there's a mysql query that would allow me to get this result but I did try to do it on PHP and didn't know where to start. Below is the php code that i'm currently using:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY user";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo '</br>Customer: '.$row['customer'].'</br>Phone: '.$row['phone'].'</br>Products: '.$row['productid'].'</br>';
}
```

I know that i need to add a code inside the while statements that would do "while it's the same user, concatenate productid in to a variable" but I just can't translate it into codes.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Comment: check out the `GroupBy` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT 
  customer, 
  phone, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(productid SEPARATOR ', ') as product_ids
FROM table1
GROUP BY customer
```

Comment: Grouping on `phone` is probably superfluous; if it's the same customer and one only one phone number, it's unnecessary; if it's possible two customer names are different people (and different phone numbers), grouping should be done on the row ID column, not the name.

Comment: Won't MySQL complain that he doesn't know how to aggregate the column? Coming form Postgresql I know that you have to specify all the columns in the group by clause when aggregating values using sum or concatenation, I though this was also valid for MySQL.

Comment: MSSQL also requires that, but MySQL doesn't. This is a trip-up if you go in the opposite direction (as I did once, long ago).

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks for the infos, I'll look deeper into it.

Comment: I was too seeing too that the `phone` is superfluous, I was also reading [this](http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/) article and what kind of problems you could have when using non grouped value and I must say that I like the postgres approach better.

Comment: I appreciate you guys help on this. I've been thinking about what Jared said. There could be customers that has same name but different people and phone numbers so I added a customer ID column. Thanks again!